# Array offset without losing values

Tags: php, array

After looking through PHP.net documentation for hours, is this the best way to offset an array from start to finish by using `array_slice()` with `array_merge()`?

For example: `$array = array(1,2,3,4)` to offset by 2 to get return `$array = array(3,4,1,2)`.

Here's the code I'm using it in:

```php
    $team = 2;
    $course = array(
    array('title'=>1,  'hole'=> 'h01', 'shot1'=>'value="-3"', 'shot2'=>'value="-2"', 'shot3'=>'value="-1"', 'shot4'=>'value="0"', 'shot5'=>'disabled="disabled"'),
    array('title'=>2,  'hole'=> 'h02', 'shot1'=>'value="-4"', 'shot2'=>'value="-3"', 'shot3'=>'value="-2"', 'shot4'=>'value="-1"', 'shot5'=>'value="0"'),
    array('title'=>3,  'hole'=> 'h03', 'shot1'=>'value="-3"', 'shot2'=>'value="-2"', 'shot3'=>'value="-1"', 'shot4'=>'value="0"', 'shot5'=>'disabled="disabled"'),
    array('title'=>4,  'hole'=> 'h04', 'shot1'=>'value="-2"', 'shot2'=>'value="-1"', 'shot3'=>'value="0"', 'shot4'=>'disabled="disabled"', 'shot5'=>'disabled="disabled"'),
    array('title'=>5,  'hole'=> 'h05', 'shot1'=>'value="-4"', 'shot2'=>'value="-3"', 'shot3'=>'value="-2"', 'shot4'=>'value="-1"', 'shot5'=>'value="0"')
    );

    $array1 = array_slice($course, $team);
   $array2 = array_slice($course, 0, $team);
   $merged = array_merge($array1, $array2);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind modifying the original array, you can shorten the (perfectly adequate code you have) with this:

```
$head = array_splice($course, 0, $team);  // remove and return first $team elements
$merged = array_merge($course, $head);    // append them to the end
```

You should be able to omit the temporary `$head` array by inserting the `array_splice` call into the `array_merge` call at the cost of a little code clarity. Try it out to make sure the order of operations is correct.

```
$merged = array_merge($course, array_splice($course, 0, $team));
```

**Edit:** If you're doing this once per team you can use a loop with [`array_shift`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the first element and [`array_push`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to place it at the end:

```
for ($team = 0; $team < $numTeams; $team++) {
    array_push($course, array_shift($course));
    // use $course...
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to loop 18 arrays but have different starting arrays based on team value. So for example,   `$team = 5` then output `$array = array(array(5),array(6),array(7),array(8),array(9),array(10),array(11),array(12),array(13),array(14),array(15),array(16),array(17),array(18),array(1),array(2),array(3),array(4));`

Comment: Do you have 18 different starting arrays? Or are you taking the same array and doing the above for `$team = 1`, `$team = 2`, `$team = 3`, etc?

Comment: The latter, one array with 18 different orders based on team ID.

Comment: @Conor In that case see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked best for me.

```
$team = 2;
$start = $team - 1;
$course = array(
array('title'=>1,  'hole'=> 'h01', 'shot1'=>'value="-3"', 'shot2'=>'value="-2"', 'shot3'=>'value="-1"', 'shot4'=>'value="0"', 'shot5'=>'disabled="disabled"'),
array('title'=>2,  'hole'=> 'h02', 'shot1'=>'value="-4"', 'shot2'=>'value="-3"', 'shot3'=>'value="-2"', 'shot4'=>'value="-1"', 'shot5'=>'value="0"'),
array('title'=>3,  'hole'=> 'h03', 'shot1'=>'value="-3"', 'shot2'=>'value="-2"', 'shot3'=>'value="-1"', 'shot4'=>'value="0"', 'shot5'=>'disabled="disabled"'),
array('title'=>4,  'hole'=> 'h04', 'shot1'=>'value="-2"', 'shot2'=>'value="-1"', 'shot3'=>'value="0"', 'shot4'=>'disabled="disabled"', 'shot5'=>'disabled="disabled"'),
array('title'=>5,  'hole'=> 'h05', 'shot1'=>'value="-4"', 'shot2'=>'value="-3"', 'shot3'=>'value="-2"', 'shot4'=>'value="-1"', 'shot5'=>'value="0"')
);

$slice1 = array_slice($course, $start);
$slice2 = array_slice($course, 0, $start);
$merged = array_merge($slice1, $slice2);
```